# Bash: Sort file numerically, but only where the first field matches a pattern

Tags: bash, sorting

Due to poor past naming practices, I'm left with a list of names that is proving to be a challenge to work with. The bottom line is that I want the most current name (by date) to be placed in a variable. All the names are listed (unsorted) in a file called `bar.txt`.

In this case I can't rename, and there's no way to get the actual dates of the images; these names are all I have to go on. The names can follow one of several patterns;

```
foo
YYYYMMDD-foo
YYYYMMDD##-foo
```

`foo` can be anything from a single character to a long string of letters/numbers/symbols. I am interested only in the names matching the second use case, `YYMMDD-foo`, as those are from after we started tagging consistently.

I would like to end up with a variable containing the most recent date that follows the pattern `YYMMDD-foo`.

I know `sort -k1 -n < bar.txt`, but then I'm not sure how to isolate the second pattern's results to extract what I need.

**How do I sort the file to ignore anything but the second pattern, and return the most current date?**

### Sample

Given that bar.txt looks like this;

```
test
2017120901-develop-BUILD-31
20170326-TEST-1.2.0
20170406-BUILD-40-1.2.0-test
2010818_001
```

I would want to extract `20170406-BUILD-40-1.2.0-test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your requirement involves 1) to get only files of a certain format 2) apply sorting and get only the latest file. Am using a `Awk` & `GNU sort` together to achieve it

```
awk -F'-' 'length($1) == 8' file | sort -nrk1 | head -1
20170406-BUILD-40-1.2.0-test
```

The solution works by only getting those *lines* in the file whose first column has `8` characters exactly corresponding to `YYYYMMDD` alignment. Once those filtered, `sort` applied on first field and the first line is obtained using `head`.

Comment: My bad for not making it clearer, but I can't guarantee the format will actually have the BUILD-## in it; the only thing I can guarantee is it will start with exactly 8 numbers and a dash. Would you mind editing?

Comment: @Alex: Refer my answer now